# In App Settings for Admins of SharePoint 2013 App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, administration, sharepoint-addin

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 app that I wish to deploy in the Market Place.  Is it possible to have an admin section of the app to allow the Site Administrators to add custom content configurations to the app.  I want to launch one app to the MarketPlace, but allow Administrators to change the some vieable app information (title, links to website, etc..)

Thanks,
Graham.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it all depends on what kind of app you're building and what features it comprises, because different mechanisms are available.

For instance for SharePoint-hosted apps you would have your own lists in the app-web, if you build app-parts for it, settings could be configured in a similar manner as with regular web-parts.

If you build Cloud-hosted (Provider-hosted or Auto-hosted) than you are in a totally different situation, and you would be able to have dedicated pages in the respective webs to store/read settings.

Auto-hosted app means deployed in Azure, which also means you could build ASp.NET websites (not only, but as example), with Azure database back-end. These being said, is entirelly up to you what you do with Web Application. Simply include any page in your web app and store those settings accordingly via the Web Applicaiotn. Practically, all pages as shown using the SharePoint Chrome, but otherwise they are regular web applications. (example with SQL DB - msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179902.aspx or Simpler msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179886.aspx) –

In the case of Auto-hosted app it means deployed in Azure (you need your account ready and configure in VS 2012 to ease deployment), which also means you could build ASp.NET websites (not only, but as example), with Azure database back-end. These being said, is entirelly up to you what you do with Web Application. Simply include any page in your web app and store those settings accordingly via the Web Applicaiotn. Practically, all pages as shown using the SharePoint Chrome, but otherwise they are regular web applications. (example with SQL DB - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179902.aspx or Simpler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179886.aspx)

Comment: I am working on an Auto-Hosted App, do you have any links to resources that show how to create an app configuration page for Site Administrators to configure apps downloaded from the Marketplace?

Comment: Auto-hosted app means deployed in Azure, which also means you could build ASp.NET websites (not only, but as example), with Azure database back-end. These being said, is entirelly up to you what you do with Web Application. Simply include any page in your web app and store those settings accordingly via the Web Applicaiotn. Practically, all pages as shown using the SharePoint Chrome, but otherwise they are regular web applications. (example with SQL DB  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179902.aspx or Simpler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179886.aspx)